# Counting the number of $3\times 4$ matrices with all entries either $0$ or $1$ such that no row/column contains all $0$'s

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

Problem:

> How many $3\times 4$ matrices are there with all entries either $0$ or $1$ such that there is no row or column which contains all $0$'s?

I have tried the problem using inclusion-exclusion principle but it is becoming very complicated. I started with $2^{12}$ total possibilities, then while subtracting the terms, it is becoming complicated.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try doing it by only having to do inclusion-exclusion on the rows.  There are $2^3-1 = 7$ ways to fill in each column without it having only zeros, so there are $7^4$ ways to fill in the matrix without any column having only zeros.  Now how many of those arrangements have the first row all zeros?  That will be the same as the number for the second row and the third row.  Subtract those from $7^4$.  Then how many have the first *two* rows, or the last two rows, or the outer two rows, all zeros?  Add those back in.

Comment: For the square version we have: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3924583/count-of-matrix-of-0-1-in-which-each-row-and-each-column-have-at-least-one-1?rq=1 but the method also works for rectangular matrices.